# Short Getting objects from dictionary with key to array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I got array A. 
It contains dictionaries with NSStrings for key "b".

I need to get all NSStrings in new Array.

I do not want to do it in more then 1 string of code. Is it possible?

I need it because I want to insert array of objects for key "b" in

```
  NSMutableArray *videosStr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: HERE ];
```

Or how is the shortest way to do it? ALso I need original sorting

Comment: Try this, `NSMutableArray *videosStr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [dictionayArray valueForKey:@"b"] ];`

Comment: great, have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Key Value Coding for it. Following is the sample code:

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test1" forKey:@"b"];
NSDictionary *dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test2" forKey:@"b"];
NSDictionary *dict3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test3" forKey:@"b"];
NSArray *arr = @[dict1, dict2, dict3];
NSArray * videosStr =[arr valueForKeyPath:@"b"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get all elements with key `"b"`,

```
NSMutableArray *videosStr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [dictionayArray valueForKey:@"b"] ];
```